PGPASSFILE not working in Node.js using npm package postgres
I created a .pgpass file in the user's home directory (follow instruccions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html):

vi ~/.pgpass

I added the connection details:

182.10.203.23:5432:database:username:verystrongpass

I then tested the connection using psql and it successfully connects to the database using the credentials from the file:

psql

Next, I prepared the development environment:

Created a .env file to set up the environment:


NODE_ENV=development
PGPASSFILE=/home/username/.pgpass


Installed the postgres npm package:


npm install postgres


Created a JavaScript file (test.mjs) to connect to the database:


import postgres from 'postgres'
const sql = postgres()
const data = await sqlselect * from mytable
console.log(data)\

4 Ran the script

node --env-file=.env test.mjs

I got the following error:

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

This indicates that it is trying to connect using the default localhost:5432 connection and not using the configuration from .pgpass.
How can I configure the connection to read from PGPASSFILE?

Is it supported?  I would not expect js to be based on libpq.
